# Parsing quoted and double quoted lines in Linux libreadline

Tags: c, linux, readline

I was writing my own shell with `libreadline` Linux library in C. In `readline()` its get the line from shell and parsed with space character and store it to a pointer variable. Now, I want parse those line to fetch like command line arguments that contains command and the filename to execute the command.

Here I was facing the issue, if the filename has spaced names and it parsing like below

```
myshell$ ls 'file name 1' 'file name 2' file\ name\ 3
```

The above cli is parsed like

```
ls
'file
name
1'
'file
name
2'
file\
name\
3
```

So, please help me to resolve this issue to get spaced filename from the readline.

Here the code snippet that i was calling readline.

```
    while (!done)
    {
        temp = readline (prompt);

        /* Test for EOF. */
        if (!temp)
            exit (1);

        /* If there is anything on the line, print it and remember it. */
        if (*temp)
        {
            add_history (temp);
        }

        <Other stuffs to execute the command>
    }
```

Updated the post with tokeniser.

```
    ptr = strtok(temp, " ");
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

Comment: If this is C don't tag as C++.

Comment: Where's your parsing code? Without it this just a journal entry about your cool side project.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Added the code snippet.

Comment: Think we need `add_history` as well. BTW: Have you tested what you get from: `printf("%s\n", temp);`

Comment: OT: I wonder if `<Other stuffs to execute the command>` can handle an empty line...

Comment: It's worth noting that function calls should look like `fn(args, ...)` without an interleaving space. Although C doesn't really care, it impairs readability because it implies those are two different things.

Comment: This is some code, which is better than nothing, but there's no way to reproduce your problem directly. Do you get the entire line as one string or is it tokenized on spaces already?

Comment: I was tokenising the string returned by readline with ```strtok(temp, " ")```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to do tokenization of even this level of complexity using naive application of strtok(). Even if you can make it work, the code will be unreadable and unmaintainable. There are tools (like flex) for generating tokenizers according to a specification, or you can code the logic yourself using a finite-state machine (FSM). With an FSM you'd examine each character, and take action according to the current state of the tokenizer. Some state/character combinations will cause a change of state.

For example, if you're in the "double quote" state, a space won't be treated as the end of a token. However, a double-quote character in the double quote state will signal a transition out of that state, into some other. The states and the classes of characters between them form a kind of matrix, the entries in which control what action to take on encountering each combination of state and character class.

FWIW I have a simple implementation that parses ASCII text along the lines you want; see the tokenize() function in this code:

https://github.com/kevinboone/xine-server/blob/master/client/src/string.c

If you're creating a shell, be advised that the tokenization logic in "real" shells is staggeringly complex, and usually implemented using tooling. In addition, most modern, real-world applications call for wide-character support, which adds another layer of complexity.